# adding n number of zeros after decimal

Tags: java, android

I need to give accuracy of a number entered by user till few digit. like if user enter some random value and gives that he wants accuracy till three digit then I need to round off the digit till three places after decimal. So i did something like this

```
 int index = value.indexOf('.'); 
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                String fractional = value.substring(index);

                if (fractional.length() > decimalPlaces)
                {
                    floatValue = roundOffDecimals(floatValue, decimalPlaces);
                }
            }
            retVal = new Float(floatValue);
```

but when user enters some value but do not enters any value as decimal I need to display it as dismal value with zeros as number of decimal places. 
like for 15 is his number and 3 is his accuracy then I need to display number as 15.000

I am not able to display zero after decimal when it always changes. Please help.
I tried DeciamlFormat df = new DecimalFormat("",#.##); but takes static value. And my accuracy keeps changing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The precision you *display* can be achieved with the format command.  The precision you actually *have* is something quite different.  And remember: any multiplication, division, rounding and truncation you do will *always* be an "approximation", and will *always* reduce the floating point value's accuracy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a method that returns the exact format for your decimals. Here is an example:

```
public String formatNumber(int decimals, double number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(decimals + 2);
    sb.append("#.");
    for(int i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
        sb.append("0");
    }
    return new DecimalFormat(sb.toString()).format(number);
}
```

If you don't need to change the `decimals` value so often, then you can change your method to something like:

```
public DecimalFormat getDecimalFormat(int decimals) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(decimals + 2);
    sb.append("#.");
    for(int i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
        sb.append("0");
    }
    return new DecimalFormat(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: ya, feels like this could help. I am working on your solution .

Comment: Well, I've tested this method and worked for me. I need to know how are you using it.

Comment: @AddingKnowledge one more thing: make sure you send a primitive number variable (int, long, float, double, short, byte) and not a class wrapper (`Integer`, `Float`, `Double`...).

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed use NumberFormat to do this

```
double amount = 15;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
System.out.println("The Decimal Value is:"+formatter.format(amount));
```

Comment: it will format it with three digit. and as i mentioned in question that number of zero to be added keeps changing as user can enter that tooo. So please If you could give some way so that it gives the zeros after decimal as enterd by user.

Comment: ok. In that case, i think the answer by @LuiggiMendoza above will help you.

Answer (score 3):

you can use string format:

Double area = 6

String ar = String.format("%.3f", area); ar = 6.000

Comment: perfect 1 liner