# How to add n number of zeros after a decimal?

Tags: java, bluej

I was reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895863/adding-n-number-of-zeros-after-decimal) trying to figure out how to round `12.5` to `12.50` or `12` to `12.00`.

I essentially need to round the `value` value to 2 decimal places even though the last zero will be an insignificant digit.

Comment: So, what's your question? How to do the rounding? Or the printing (which is explained in the question/answers you've linked)?

Comment: I would guess you are not really talking about "rounding" but formatting. To format a double with 2 decimal places, your could, for example, try `String.format("%.2f", 12.5);`

Comment: @DarkDust I need to round it to 2 decimal places even if it is a whole number or has one decimal place. Once it's round it, I know how to print it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Helped me too.Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use DecimalFormat class.

```
    DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat(".00");
    double val = 12.5;
    System.out.println(dc.format(val));
```

Answer (score 3):

@FlorianSchaetz had exactly what I needed. I needed to use `String.format("%.2f", 12.5);`